# Set font on custom span jQuery Mobile slider labels

Tags: jquery-mobile, slider, jquery-ui-slider

Hello kind people of the internet,

I'm prepending and appending some text content as labels on the left and right side of a jQuery Mobile range slider, which works ok, but I can't seem to get the font to behave...the font is not displaying properly, and I can't seem to set/reset the label font either within the span.

Here's a test page:
http://www.simdock.com/amort-test/dev-scratch/amort/scratchtesting-Slider-label-font-issue.html

Here's the javascript code that puts on the custom slider labels (minimum and maximum slider range values) on the left and right side of the slider:

```
 $.fn.extend({
 sliderLabels: function(left,right) {
 var $this = $(this); 
 var $sliderdiv= $this.next("div.ui-slider[role='application']");
 //
 $sliderdiv
 .prepend('<span class="ui-slider-inner-label" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:20px;">'+left+ '</span>')
 .append('<span class="ui-slider-inner-label" style="position: absolute; right:0px; bottom:20px;">'+right+ '</span>');     
  //   
 }
 });
 //
 $('#slider-PrincipleAmnt').sliderLabels('Min: $20', 'Max: $999');
```

I've tried many different iterations and attempts to explicitly set the font in the span, but alas, no luck.

I found the code originally out on the jquery forum at following link:
https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-do-i-add-text-labels-below-slider

The above link also has a jsfiddle, and the font comes out fine...so I just don't understand what I'm overlooking.
http://jsfiddle.net/cUNyr/1/

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Update note: both Jack and Taifun offered some very helpful tips and ideas, however, I'm still struggling with what and how exactly to alter on the CSS?  I'm also puzzled/frustrated about how I would even be able to determine in the text font even has a 'shadow' in the first place?...here's the span CSS as shown in Firebug:

```
<span class="ui-slider-inner-label" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:20px;">Min: $20</span>
```

There is no 'text shadow' attribute showing up in Firebug.  Soooo, hmmmmm, what do I look for? and with what tool?  Where is the 'text shadow' coming from? What would the CSS over-ride be?

At this point, how the odd-ball font appears, and how to fix it is still a bit of a mystery...but I'm sure there's an important lesson to be learned (a Zen thing: value your bugs) for the next time I run into a similar situation. Again: ya'll have been super helpful...and I feel like I'm close to having this figured out...but alas, not quite there yet.

Comment: I'm not really sure what your asking, but if your referring to the `text-shadow` then you can just override that with some CSS.

Comment: Hi Jack, mucho thanks for the feedback as there's a learning opportunity here. What's still a bit confusing for me is after using Firebug to look at the span, there does not seem to be any CSS for just 'text-shadow'?

Comment: Hi again Jack, What Taifun pointed was most helpfull, and was right about the theme...and I had no idea the slider theme could affect a 'text-shadow' of the slider label. But I'm still uncertain about two other points: #1-What exactly would I be over-riding and setting with CSS to do the override of the font?, as again in Firebug I don't see anything specific for a text-shadow...and I don't have much experience creating CSS over-rides either and #2-Why wouldn't explicitly setting the text font within the Javascript for creating the span work?...why does a separate CSS file need to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your example you are using `data-theme="b" data-track-theme="a"`. Removing that you get a readable font. However if you like to use that theme, you can override the CSS as @Jack mentioned, more info [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/themes.html).

> **Overriding themes**
>
> The themes are meant as a solid starting point, but are meant to be
>   customized. Since everything is controlled by CSS, it's easy to use a
>   web inspector tool to identify the style properties you want to
>   modify.

**see also [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/ZqBmE/)**

**EDIT**: there is no need to create an external custom CSS file.... You can add this `<style>` in the head of your html to override your CSS, see also this **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4GY8/)**

```
<style>
   .ui-slider-inner-label {
     text-shadow:none;
     color:black;
     font-weight:normal;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: Note I added the following alteration to the span, and it took off the text shadow, set to blank and normal:   text-shadow:none; color:black; font-weight:normal

Comment: Hi Taifun, thanks mucho for the additional feed back...yet another way to alter the CSS is to add the CSS to head section. Very nice to have a solid example.  To tell the truth, CSS seems a bit brittle and complex to me at this point...I'm kinda flailing and hacking at it using other folks code examples, without a solid understanding...sigh: I guess ya gotta start somewhere.  Again: Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Note again the hints provided by Jack and Taifun were most helpful...but I did finally find a direct easy way to fix the issue by directly setting the text-shadow to none, then forcing the text to black (as was still displaying in white), and then to normal font (as was displaying in bold).  So, while I didn't determine what exactly was inducing the shadow text, I did manage to at least reset it to a regular font using inline techniques, and avoided having to create an external custom CSS file.

```
  //
  $sliderdiv
  .prepend('<span class="ui-slider-inner-label" style="position: absolute; left:0px; top:20px; text-shadow:none; color:black; font-weight:normal">'+left+ '</span>')
  .append('<span class="ui-slider-inner-label" style="position: absolute; right:0px; bottom:20px; text-shadow:none; color:black; font-weight:normal">'+right+ '</span>');      
  //
```