# Custom jquery mobile slider labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I am struggling to get this to work correctly. I want to add tick marks and custom labels to jquery mobile's slider widget (https://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/) First I would like to add tick markers at 0, 25, 50, 75, and 100. Above each tick I would like a custom string/label. Lastly I would like the labels to scale with the jquery slider as the size of the page changes. Right now I can add labels without ticks, but it only fits for one screen size.

```js
    
        $( ".ui-content" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var newState = $("#slider-0").val();
        } );
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding: 40px;">

        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="labels" >
                <label for="points" style="display: inline; padding: 55px;">volume off</label>
                <label style="display: inline; padding: 50px;" for="points">quiet</label>
                <label style="display: inline; padding: 50px;" for="points">normal</label>
                <label style="display: inline; padding: 50px" for="points">loud</label>
                <label style="display: inline; padding: 50px" for="points">max</label>
            </div>
            <input type="range" data-highlight="true" data-popup-enabled="true" name="slider-0" id="slider-0" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="a"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried using CSS % for the padding, but that did not work as expected. I have also tried the suggestions here [jQuery UI Slider Labels Under Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10224856/jquery-ui-slider-labels-under-slider),  here [Add tick marks to jQuery slider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648963/add-tick-marks-to-jquery-slider) and here [Set font on custom span jQuery Mobile slider labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870987/set-font-on-custom-span-jquery-mobile-slider-labels) but I could not get the ticks and labels to stay lined up with the slider. I thought this would be a simple formatting issue, but I am having trouble putting everything together. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

After some more research I stumbled upon this blog: https://css-tricks.com/equidistant-objects-with-css/ from that I tried the option using flex. So I added the flex styling to my labels class to get `<div class="labels" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">`. I tested this on chrome and safari it seems to work fine. But I am still not sure how to get the ticks to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while back I wrote a blog entry for customizing the jQM slider widget:

https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/04/21/fun-with-the-slider-widget/

In it is an example for adding tick marks and labels that scale with the slider. Here is the code updated to have the labels above the slider instead of below it and a demo of the code running in CodePen:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="example2a" class="example" >
        <label for="theSlider2a">Slider with Tick marks:</label>
        <input type="range" name="theSlider2a" id="theSlider2" min="0" max="100" value="60" />
    </div>
```

**JavaScript** (put your desired label text inside the spans)

```
var ticks  = '<div class="sliderTickmarks "><span>volume off</span></div>';
    ticks += '<div class="sliderTickmarks "><span>Quiet</span></div>';
    ticks += '<div class="sliderTickmarks "><span>Normal</span></div>';
    ticks += '<div class="sliderTickmarks "><span>Loud</span></div>';
    ticks += '<div class="sliderTickmarks "><span>Max</span></div>';

$("#example2a .ui-slider-track").prepend(ticks);
```

**CSS**

```
.sliderTickmarks{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;    
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #888;
}
.sliderTickmarks span{
    position: relative;
    left: 100%; top: -135%;
    margin-left: -16px;
    font-size: 12px; font-weight: normal; white-space: nowrap;
}
.ui-slider-track > div.sliderTickmarks:first-child{
    border-right: 0; width: 0;
}
.ui-slider-track > div.sliderTickmarks:first-child span{
    margin-left: -5px;
}
.ui-slider-track > div.sliderTickmarks:last-of-type{
     border-right: 0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/ezanker/pen/VmGMVz)**

Comment: the section in the blog post about customizing the slider background, is also interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Might sound dirty, using table to display well these labels.

```
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <table class="labels">
            <tr>
              <td>volume off</td>
              <td>quiet</td>
              <td>normal</td>
              <td>loud</td>
              <td>max</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="range" data-highlight="true" data-popup-enabled="true" name="slider-0" id="slider-0" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="a"/>
        </div>
```

Comment: Have you tested it ?

Comment: I don't have the problem you mentionned

Answer (score 0):

Try giving this a go. I agree the flexbox approach is the best way. The answer to your tick problem could be an offset div with a black border-left.

```js
    //I didn't touch this
        $( ".ui-content" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var newState = $("#slider-0").val();
        } );
```

```css
.labels {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 92.5%;
  margin-left:7.5%
}
.verticalLine {
    height:10px;
    border-left: solid black;
    margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes"/>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>



<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" style="padding: 40px;">
        <!-- Remove padding. Add tick divs -->
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <div class="labels" >
            <label for="points" style="display: inline;">volume off
              <div class="verticalLine"></div>
            </label>               
            <label style="display: inline;" for="points">quiet
              <div class="verticalLine"></div>
            </label>
            <label style="display: inline;" for="points">normal
              <div class="verticalLine"></div>
            </label>
            <label style="display: inline;" for="points">loud
              <div class="verticalLine"></div>
            </label>
            <label style="display: inline;" for="points">max
              <div class="verticalLine"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
            <input type="range" data-highlight="true" data-popup-enabled="true" name="slider-0" id="slider-0" value="50" min="0" max="100" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="a"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```